# Position Calculator - Keep menu from disappearing when mouse over menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, position, calculator

This fiddle does exactly what i'm looking for using the Position Calculator plugin and javascript to position it but is there a way for me to prevent the menu from hiding when the mouse is over the menu as the I require the list items for the menu to be clickable.

http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/1657/

```
$(".placeholder").on('mouseover', function() {
    var $menu = $("#menu").show();
    var pos = $.PositionCalculator( {
    target: this,
    targetAt: "top right",
    item: $menu,
    itemAt: "top left",
    flip: "both"
}).calculate();

$menu.css({
    top: parseInt($menu.css('top')) + pos.moveBy.y + "px",
    left: parseInt($menu.css('left')) + pos.moveBy.x + "px"
});

$(".placeholder").mouseout(function() {
    $("#menu").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".placeholder").mouseout(function() {
$("#menu").hide();
});
```

remove this piece of code